# JQuery :hidden doesn't work in IE8

Tags: jquery

With jquery 1.3.2, 
in **IE7**, **$("tr.football:hidden").length** returns **8**, however,
in **IE8** it returns **0**.

Did you ever met the same issue? How did you workaround this?

Thanks.

Comment: appears this is still apparent as late as 1.4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a bug,  check the forum: [jquery forum bug report](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hidden-visible-broken-in-ie8)

Comment: For completeness, I would suggest changing the name of the link to something more descriptive.  It looks like you're just posting a link to JQuery in general instead of the useful link you actually provided.

Comment: Thanks, will change the link title

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest upgrading to the latest version of JQuery 1.4.4.  There are 4 other versions of JQuery that are ahead of the one you're running, and I'd hate to see you struggle to find a solution to a problem that may be fixed in the latest JQuery release.

Of course, if the problem still exists after upgrading, there are some other things you can try:

- Make sure your HTML validates.  JavaScript will sometimes have trouble parsing your HTML correctly if it doesn't meet the standards that the browsers were implemented in respect to.
- See if you can find a workaround, such as using the style "display:none" selector or maybe binding an extra class on your hidden elements.

Here is a link to the Google Libraries API.  You can link directly to the latest version of JQuery 1.4.4:
http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery